# Finding adjacent nodes

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dictionary

I have a series of polygons, represented in 3 vector3 objects. ie:

```
{
  "a": [1,2],
  "b": [3,4],
  "c": [5,6]
}
```

Where `a,b,c` are the three points of a triangle, and the index's `0,1` are `x,y` respectively.

If this object was in an array, with 50 or so other triangles, each having a shared vertex, what algorithm per se could I potentially run to create some sort of array of indexes of sibling triangles?

Comment: If it's only 50 triangles it doesn't worth the time to over-engineer it. Just check every pair and determine if they are siblings/

Comment: Only 1 shared vertex or at least 1?
Do you assume that is ever possible to find a sibling triangle with a shared vertex?

Comment: @amit - There are about 400+ triangles, used 50 as an arbitrary number being that surely the algorithm should scale? But yeah, maybe like you said there comes a point where you need to optimize the resolution as opposed to brute force. But with that in mind, I need this operation to happen pretty quick.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find triangles that share a common vertex, create an object whose keys are the vertices and whose values are arrays of triangles or indices/keys in an array or object of triangles.

Say you have an array of triangles that doesn't change and you store the triangles by index of that array:

```
var tria = [
    {a: [1, 2], b: [3, 4], c: [0, 6]}, 
    // more triangles ...
];

var adjacent = {};

function addAdjacent(vertex, tria) {
    if (!(vertex in adjacent)) adjacent[vertex] = [];
    adjacent[vertex].push(tria);

}

for (var i = 0; i < tria.length; i++) {
    var t = tria[i];

    addAdjacent(t.a, i);
    addAdjacent(t.b, i);
    addAdjacent(t.c, i);
}
```

Then you can look up vertices in `adjacent` and get an array of connected triangles. This function tells you whether two triangles are adjacent. If so, it returns the common node, if not, it returns `null`:

```
function isAdjacent(x, y) {
    var t = tria[x];

    if (t.a in adjacent && ~adjacent[t.a].indexOf(y)) return t.a;
    if (t.b in adjacent && ~adjacent[t.b].indexOf(y)) return t.b;
    if (t.c in adjacent && ~adjacent[t.c].indexOf(y)) return t.c;

    return null;
}
```

If you want to find triangles with common edges, you can use this approach, too. Your key then consists of two vertices. You must find a way to make the ordering of the vertices unique, so that the edge `[1, 2], [5, 0]` is equivalent to its reverse, `[5, 0], [1, 2]`. One way to do this is to make the smaller vertex the first point of the edge. (Smaller means the vertex with the smaller x coordinate and if that is equal n both points the vertex with the smaller y coordinate.)